Why it is important to specify which note gets a beat in time signature?
I'm learning the basics of music theory. As I understood, in time signatures, the upper number says how many beats there are in a measure, and the lower number says which note gets a beat. I'm wondering why it is necessary to specify which note corresponds to a beat. For example, four quarter notes in 4/4 time signature is equivalent to four eighth notes in 4/8 time signature, and so on. So with the freedom to choose notes with different values, I'm not sure why musicians should specify which note should get a beat.

Part of the reason for this is historical: time signatures have their origin in fractional proportions.  And sometimes these were just a single number, 2 or 3.  In French music, single-digit time signatures persisted well into the 18th century at least.  So in a certain sense, the question's premise is incorrect: it isn't actually important to specify which note gets a beat; we just do it by convention.  (And, for compound time signatures, we usually don't do it at all, because the note that gets the beat is dotted; the lower number of the time signature frequently specifies 1/3 of the beat.)

What you say is true. But it's the ease of writing and reading that counts (!).
Using, for instance, lots of semiquavers could be avoided by changing the time signature, and making them into quavers instead.
So, no hard and fast rules, just common sense, and making things as easy for all as possible.

Thanks for the answer. So, composers take into account the complexity/readability of the sheet for selecting an appropriate lower number for the time signature?

It is not just about reducing the amount of black ink on a page. The time signature also gives some of the information that a performer needs to decide on a suitable speed. A piece of music in 3/8 will generally be understood to sound quicker than a piece in 3/4. This is not always the case though - hymnbook styles have changed in the last hundred years and a hymn tune that was once written in 3/2 will now be written in 3/4 but played exactly the same.

@Peter - more often than not, there will be a tempo marking. If not in bpm, then in general 'allegro, andante' terms.
